# VSCode - Formatting - Whenever I close a tag it jumps to the far left. How to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I open a tag, write something inside and then when I type '>' in closing tag, it jumps to the beginning of the line and I have to hit a tab several times to get it into the right place. How to fix it?

```
          <div>
            some text
</div>
```

Comment: Check this solutions: https://superuser.com/questions/1474913/vs-code-closing-tag-jumps-to-the-left